# template renders before my variables can initialize

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, multi-select

I'm trying to have my vue file accept an array of objects from the parent and create a multiselect with it but the vue template keeps rendering before my variables can initialize so I get a message saying the array that the multiselect is using is equal to null

I have tried creating using a computed, mounted, and created, component to the file but nothing seems to work

```
 <template>
    <div id="my-app">

        <multiselect v-model="value" :options="prop2" :custom-label="FullName" placeholder="Select one" label="name" track-by="_id" @update="updateProp1()"></multiselect>
        <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
    name: "comp",
    components: {
        Multiselect
    },
    props: ['prop1', 'prop2'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            value: null,
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        this.getProp1();
    },
    computed: {
        prop2() {
            return this.prop2;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        FullName ({ FirstName, LastName }) {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName
        },
        getProp1(){
            for(var p2 in this.prop2){
                if(this.prop1 == p2._id){
                    this.value = prop1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
        updateProp1(newProp1){
            this.prop1 = newProp1;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm expecting a multiselect with default values in the "value" variable and the all the available options in the "options" variable. Selecting anything with the multiselect will overwrite the "value" variable. Though what I'm actually getting is two empty arrays that sometimes works. I think this is happening because vue is asynchronous but even knowing that I'm not sure how I can prevent it.

Comment: some code would help

Comment: I updated it with my code

Comment: Have you tried setting in your template  `:options="props"` ?

Comment: yes, nothing seems to work. I've also tried putting it in a v-if container with the condition to check if prop1 and prop2 are null. now  it's just constantly loading because the two values are always null even though I should have assigned it upon creation.

Comment: Why do you need the **computed** **prop2()**? Can't you just use the **props** **prop2**?

Comment: isn't it bad to directly alter a prop?